# Json; CamelCase to underscore in JSON serialisation

Tags: json, serialization, jackson

I encountered a situation in  deserialising json to POJO and serialising it back to json

**Deserialising**:
Here the json is received with camel cased params and the pojo has an appropriate JsonCreator and this works

eg- received json - {"userId":"id"}

**Serialisation**:
Here I have to serialise this POJO into JSON again to send to another service. and the parameter should be SNAKE cased with underscore

eg - variable **userId** should be changed to **user_id** while serialising

has anyone faced this situation before? has some tips to proceed ?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding @JsonProperty("user_id") annotation in your pojo class. I hope it should solve the issue.